# Tensorflow not outputting any log information in Spyder?

Tags: python, tensorflow, spyder

What it says on the tin. This issue:

https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3777

Has been open for years now. Surely someone has gotten tensorflow to output information to the Spyder console?

For the record, my Tensorflow works. I ran the simple example here:

```
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
print(sess.run(c))
```

And it just gives me the answer, not the logging information I want. My actual code that I'm trying to run does the same thing (answer, no log info), but since it takes so long I would really like the console output.

But I have no idea how to actually implement the code snippet it has there.

Answer (score 3):

I've had no trouble with Spyder printing logging information. You may need to enable logging in your application:

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
```

A lot of developers set the `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` environment variable to 3 to prevent TensorFlow from whining about the device's supported capabilities. I'd check that.

If you run the following code, will it print anything?

```
tf.logging.info('Hi there!')
```

Comment: Yeah that line prints, but even if I set the level to something else it doesn't work for the standard example up there or my actual program. Oh well, guess I'll black box it lol thanks for the help :P